# Magento: generate image cache

Tags: magento, caching

When I empty the 'image cache'

I run this script:

```
<?php
apc_clear_cache();
require '../app/Mage.php';
function getImages($store){
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store);
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $products->addAttributeToSelect('name');
    foreach($products as $product) {
        echo 'product: '.$product->name.' IMAGE: '.$product->getImageUrl().'<br>';
    }

}

foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $website) {
    echo $website;
    foreach ($website->getGroups() as $group) {
        $stores = $group->getStores();
        foreach ($stores as $store) {
            getImages($store);
        }
    }
}

echo 'done';
```

What I want is that all the images in the cache get refreshed, but they don't (only when I load the urls in the browser)

How can I do this?

Comment: If you just show images urls they won't refresh, you have to load them. You can create do this by opening them (with curl, file_get_contents, ajax call, echo <img src="url"/> etc.

Comment: @dagfr thanks. But when I use the $product->getImageUrl() I get the placeholder (see below) but I want the name of the image that is about te generated. media/catalog/product/cache/2/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg

Answer (score 2):

To create the images, you need to use the `Mage::helper('catalog/image')`.

The problem is,  that only the template file knows in which dimensions the image is needed, therefore you have to copy the code from the template (and all the other places where you have product images) and create the different sizes of the images via the helper.

One tipp: The create is in the `__toString()` method.

Comment: Great, I'm almost there... Maybe it's a plan to search through all the .phtml file and search (regex) for 'resize(x)' (where x = something)